# TypeError: encoding without a string argument for razorpay webhook secret verification error

Tags: django, webhooks, razorpay

I am trying verify if the webhook came  from Razorpay but getting following error.

TypeError: encoding without a string argument

Here is the code:

```
webhook_secret = MY_WEBHOOK_SECRET
signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
jsondata = json.loads(request.body)
client = razorpay.Client(auth=(MY_KEY, MY_SIGNATURE))
verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(jsondata, signature, webhook_secret)
```

I'm getting error in the last line. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Documents\BoosterKick_software\BoosterKick\pages\views.py", line 168, in razorpay_webhook
    verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(jsondata, signature, webhook_secret)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\razorpay\utility\utility.py", line 25, in verify_webhook_signature
    self.verify_signature(body, signature, secret)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekanth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\razorpay\utility\utility.py", line 30, in verify_signature
    body = bytes(body, 'utf-8')
TypeError: encoding without a string argument

Comment: Hi, please post your entire stacktrace for this error.

Comment: Show us the full error trace (remove your API key if it's shown). But maybe this question can better be asked to the folks at Razorpay. Also, check the values of `jsondata`, `signature` and `webhook_secret` before you call their API.

Comment: So `body` isn't what it's expecting. Check your `jsondata`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the question to add full error trace.

Comment: `jsondata` is dictionary or list object, not a string. Try passing `request.body` directly to the web hook check.

Comment: I got the same error when I passed request.body instead of jsondata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webhook_secret = MY_WEBHOOK_SECRET
signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
jsondata = json.loads(request.body)
client = razorpay.Client(auth=(MY_KEY, MY_SIGNATURE))
client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(json.dumps(jsondata, separators=(',', ':')), signature, webhook_secret)
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Django it's not really required to convert the request body to `json` and back to `string`. This process kept giving me signature verification error. Just  decoding the body will do the trick. So the code is as follows:

```
webhook_secret = MY_WEBHOOK_SECRET
signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
body = request.body.decode()
client = razorpay.Client(auth=(MY_KEY, MY_SIGNATURE))
client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(body, signature, webhook_secret)
```

This worked for me. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68445342) answer and [this issue](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/issues/65#issuecomment-485752662) for reference.