# Razorpay Signature Verification Failed in python

Tags: python-3.7, webhooks, razorpay

I am verifying the payment status done using the razorpay payment links using a webhook. I have added the webhook to the RazorPay webhook section with payment_links as the active elements. I am getting a payment completed indication while using the payment link. But the webhook is throwing this error.

This is how I am verifying the signature

```
webhook_secret = "abc"  
webhook_signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("xyz", "pqr"))
payload_body = json.dumps(request.json, separators=(',', ':'))
verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(payload_body, webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
print(verify)
```

Also tried it with

```
payload_body = json.dumps(request.data, separators=(',', ':'))
```

But I keep getting the error,

```
razorpay.errors.SignatureVerificationError: Razorpay Signature Verification Failed
```

I tried like this

```
verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(request.data.decode('utf-8'), webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
print(verify)
```

The output is None

**Edited**

I have tried the below methods but none of them work

```
1)  verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(json.dumps(request.data, separators=(',', ':')), webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
        print("verification of signature {}".format(verify))
```

Resulted in TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable.

```
2)  verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(json.dumps(request.json, separators=(',', ':')), webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
        print("verification of signature {}".format(verify))
        #razorpay.errors.SignatureVerificationError: Razorpay Signature Verification Failed

3) verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':')), webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
    print("verification of signature {}".format(verify))
```

2 and 3 resulted in razorpay.errors.SignatureVerificationError: Razorpay Signature Verification Failed

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Django the use `request.body` instead of `request.json` to get  raw body and send it to `verify_webhook_signature` method after decoding. Here is the example code -

```py
def verify_payment(request):
    payload_body = request.body.decode()
    webhook_secret = "abc"  
    webhook_signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=("xyz", "pqr"))
    verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(payload_body, 
        webhook_signature, webhook_secret)
    print(verify)
```

You have to decode the body before verifying because of this issue https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/issues/121 otherwise it will raise a TypeError.

And If you are using Flask the use `request.data` instead of `request.json` and other steps are same.

Comment: as per the razorpay docs, we need to use the response body with out parsing it. decoding the body will change the request body right?

Comment: Yes, decoding the body changes it to string. Actually if you look into the source code verify signature webhook then you will observe that it first parse the body to bytes which if already in bytes raise a Type error thats why I decode the body to parse it to string first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django with rest_framework, request.data will give a dict and don't do json.dumps(response.data).Instead use response.body.decode() and pass it to verify_webhook_signature.it will work.
Reference - https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/issues/65#issuecomment-485752662